# Send the client JSON with Users.on('resetPasswordRequest') in loopback

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopback

I use method Users.on('resetPasswordRequest') in loopback to retrieve the password

```
Users.on('resetPasswordRequest', function (info) {
    var html = 'abcxyz';
    Users.app.models.Email.send({
      to: info.email,
      from: 'abc@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Password reset',
      html: html
    }, function (err ,email) {
      if (err) return console.log('> error sending password reset email');
      console.log('> sending password reset email to:', info.email);
    });
  });
```

How do I send JSON formatted for client?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a [remote hook](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Remote+hooks) to the `User` model. I would recommend [extending](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/APIC/Extending+built-in+models) the built-in user model to do so.

From there, you have access to the `ctx.res` ExpressJS response object. You can change the response object as you would like from there.